# Configuring and Hosting Cakephp website into Bluehost Shared Server

Tags: cakephp, web-hosting

I have created a website using cakephp 2.3.9 in my local host. i dont know how to upload it into my bluehost webservice
i have some doubts rgarding this.

1. How to change the database.php file (database name, uname, password, host name etc..)
2. Is there any additional configration needed for cakephp?
3. I herad about removing tmp files and logs. how can we do this
4. How to  dump our database into server and how to make it accessible.

If any one ca give a detailed description about this, it will useful for all  beginner cakephp developers.If any body can do this..please help all developers who struggling to upload their files into a hared server.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to change the database.php file (database name, uname, password, host name etc..)

I don't believe you are really asking *how to change* but *what to change it to*. You will need to create a new database and user from bluehost's cpanel. Use the database create wizard to help you. Use those values for the input of `database.php`. Db server is localhost.

> Is there any additional configration needed for cakephp?

We will assume that if you are asking such basic questions then you haven't touched anything that will require special handling. Just make sure `.htaccess` files are copied to the server too.

> I heard about removing tmp files and logs. how can we do this

Go inside `app/tmp` directory and remove all **files**. Make sure the directory structure is not changed - that is subfolders are not deleted.

> How to dump our database into server and how to make it accessible.

Dump your local database with something like `mysqldump -uuser -p db > db.sql` and then use that file to import it in your new database with bluehost's `phpmyadmin`. Obviously you will need to change user and db to reflect your local user and db name.